# Is there a way to increase or decrease a number with a shifter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling

Im looking for a event handler where I hold a shifter and either move it to the left to decrease the value of a number or move it to the right and increase the value of a number. Links to the documentation would be nice.

Thanks

EDITED

So thanks to the users on this post, I came up with this way instead

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function mySlideChange(){
var sliderValue = document.getElementById("slider").value;
var display = document.getElementById("display");

display.innerHTML = sliderValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<header>

</header>

<body>

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" id="slider"        

onchange="mySlideChange()">
<span id="display">50</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you mean a slider?

Comment: i guess you should use `onchange` event  (in jQuery `.change()`) on an `input` type `range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

**JavaScript**:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
    display = document.getElementById("display");

var value;

slider.onchange = function(){
    value = this.value;
    display.innerHTML = value;
}
```

or **jQuery**:

```
$("#slider").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#display").html(value);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" id="slider">
<span id="display">50</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing all possible ways. I mean there could be more but this works for me. Im trying to adjust image Hue and Saturation. Thanks!!!

Comment: You're very welcome! @Carlitos happy to help :-) if you run into any problems along the way, be sure to let me know! :D

Comment: I used your code and formatted it differently. Not really a fan of anonymous functions.

Comment: See Edits in main question and thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. The [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/) library is a small JavaScript/jQuery polyfill for the HTML5 `<input type="range">` slider element.

Comment: Would you say that is supported by all browsers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Supports all major browsers including IE8+